# writing content of vector to file c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I've tried to write my vector content into a file. To do that I've written a piece of code like:

```
int main()
{
    ofstream outputfile("test.txt");
    vector<int>temp;
    temp.push_back(1);
    temp.push_back(2);
    temp.push_back(3);
    for(int i=0;i<temp.size();i++)
        outputfile<<temp[i]<<"\n";
}
```

When I write this I can easly do what I wanted. the content of file is:

1
2
3

However, when I want to write my vector to file from reverse(like below).I get nothing.Just empty file.Is there anyone to help me ? Thanks in advance.

```
for(int i=temp.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
    outputfile<<temp[i]<<"\n";
```

Comment: You start one past the end of the `vector`.

Comment: @BoBTFish Sorry I correct this mistake. It was in the right place in my real code. So, problem is't that

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/K0jnYI). If your code is actually giving you an empty file (once it's flushed and/or closed), the problem must be in something you haven't shown.

Comment: All the answers you got till now missed the point of the question.  The code works for me also, even though I would change it to use a reverse_iterator.

Answer (score 8):

You may use

```
std::copy(temp.rbegin(), temp.rend(),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(outputfile, "\n"));
```

And this code:

```
for(int i=temp.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
    outputfile<<temp[i]<<"\n";
```

works fine on my windows with vs12.

Comment: Do people actually find this more comprehensible than a simple for loop?  Anyway, it doesn't really address the question of *why* his for loop isn't working, because it should.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Once you're used to it, yes (at least I do). Because you don't need to look & make sure the loop does what it seems to do.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes.  After trying to track down errors in custom loops where the conditions were set in odd ways (e.g. starting at 1 and doing < instead of <=), using the algorithms makes the code much more readable.

Comment: @Angew: You still need to make sure the arguments are correct.  The amount of time that takes is, for me, indistinguishable from the amount of time it takes to check the parameters to such a simple for loop.  But to each his own.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it all in 1 line:

```
std::copy(temp.rbegin(), temp.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(outputFile, "\n"));
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Since in my real problem,my  vector size will be upto 10000and efficiency is important, will the copying process cause problem ?

Comment: @caesar No more than anything else.  The largest part of the time will probably be 1) the IO itself, then 2) the conversion to text.  For the rest, the copy will do pretty much what you do in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

use a reverse iterator:

```
for (std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator it = myvector.rbegin(); it != myvector.rend(); ++it)
```

or in your code, start the for loop from `size() - 1` :

```
for(int i=temp.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
```

instead of

```
for(int i=temp.size();i>=0;i--)
```

Comment: I think you meant reverse_iterator, with rbegin() and rend()

Answer (score 0):

```
std::copy(head_buff.rbegin(), head_buff.rend(),
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(data_pack, "\n"));
```

but use `#include<fstram>#include<iterator> #include<osstream>`
second method is traverse entire vector and copy the contents to a string 
then write the string into ofstream 
ie

```
std::string somthing;
for(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i = temp.begin();i!=temp.end(); ++i)
 {
     something+=*i;
 }
```

then write string (something) to ofstream ie

```
std::ofstram output;
output.open("test.txt",std::ios_base::trunc)
if(output.fail())
  std::cerr<<"unable to open the file"std::endl;
output << something;
//after writing close file
 output.close();
```